# There is a possibility to use let's encrypt certificate for RabbitMQ server?

Tags: ssl, openssl, rabbitmq, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I currently have a domain named "rabbitmq.<server>.com". I wan't to add SSL certificates to do a AMQPS connection.

I took my nginx certificates generated by certbot (let's encrypt) for the rabbitmq dashboard and i put them into rabbitmq configurations:

```
#listeners.tcp = none

listeners.ssl.default = 5671

ssl_options.cacertfile = /etc/rabbitmq/certs/fullchain.pem
ssl_options.certfile   = /etc/rabbitmq/certs/cert.pem
ssl_options.keyfile    = /etc/rabbitmq/certs/privkey.pem
ssl_options.verify     = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = true
```

After a restart rabbitmq work and i can diagnostic my connection with openssl on my client computer:

```
openssl s_client -connect rabbitmq.<server>.com:5671 -cert cert.pem -key privkey.pem -CAfile fullchain.pem -verify 8 -verify_hostname rabbitmq.<server>.com
```

But openssl raise an error:

```
00864C1001000000:error:0A000418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1588:SSL alert number 48
```

I tried to change the `verify_peer` by `verify_none` and the SSL client work:

```
...
SSL handshake has read 4579 bytes and written 405 bytes
Verification error: unable to get issuer certificate
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 2 (unable to get issuer certificate)
---
...
AMQP    closed
```

But i don't appreciate to remove security. And my python pika client doesn't work.

My first question is i am doing the job well ? Do i need to take the server certificates (ca, cert, key) or i need to regenerate another for the client ?

Answer (score 1):

SSL alert number 48 means "unknown_ca". The server cannot verify the client certificate you've sent because it does not find any path to the CA's trusted by the server. You might be missing the root CA for cert the signer of your cert?

Comment: Okay, I don't know which files (.pem), do i need to add into my trusted certificates. With let's encrypt i have 4 files cert.pem, chain.pem, fullchain.pem, privkey.pem

Comment: Sadly no, my rabbitmq server is still in amqp.

Answer (score 0):

ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert should be set to false, unless your server must verify where the connection comes from. In that case, it must know the client certificate provider…
It is not a huge security problem, if you ensure that a client cannot login without password. The connection will be secured.

With letsencrypt, the configuration is as follow:

```
management.ssl.cacertfile           = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
management.ssl.certfile             = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
management.ssl.keyfile              = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
```

Beware of the permissions modifications after renewals.